# Pretty output of dataframe in Jupyter

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have two installation of iPython notebook on a remote ubuntu and on a local osx. And when I try to output pandas data frame I got the different output. See screenshots.

[image: Jupyter (ubuntu):]
[image: IPython (osx):]

I want pretty tables on ubuntu in jupyter.

What should I do? I've searched a lot, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with clean new installation to virtualenv through pip.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the ones above there is another nice tool `[IpyTable][1]`

```
# create dummy data:
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn, randint
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': randn(1000), 'b': randn(1000),'N': randint(100, 1000, (1000)), 'x': 'x'})

from ipy_table import make_table, set_row_style
#apply_theme('basic')
table = make_table(df[0:10].values.tolist(), len(df.columns))
set_row_style(0, color='lightGreen')
table
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might help to explicitly call the `display` function to render the table properly.

```
from Ipython.display import display
df_xyz=(...)
display(df)
```

Comment: Jupyter should automatically `display(...)` the last expression of each cell, if this doesn't happen, it's weird that explicitly calling `display(...)` makes the difference.